Вразнос или в разнос?
Не совсем понимаю, почему "вразнос" рекомендуется писать слитно, если между частями существительного и предлога можно вставить определение и задать падежный вопрос
Например:

И тут моя бабушка пошла в (полный) разнос. Пошла (во что) в разнос.


Правильно: вразнос

Из словарей:
Русский орфографический словарь.
вразнос, нареч.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ВРАЗНОС, нареч. 1. Разг. Разнося (товары) по улицам, по 
дворам. Торговать, продавать в. 2. Разг. Очень сильно, 
вовсю. Критиковать, ругать в. 3. Проф. Работая в режиме 
саморазрушения от больших перегрузок (о механизмах). 
Дизель работал в.


Но почему в литературе пишут по-разному?


Правила не знают или это "протестное" письмо? Или, может, влияние прежней орфографической нормы?
Пойти в разнос Пойти вразнос
Примеры:
 М-да, на фоне стресса моя фантазия пошла в разнос. 2022.
 Машина пошла в разнос, направляя всё возрастающий поток 
 энергию на свой разгон (2018).

 Параметры расходятся, система утрачивает свойство  
 самоадекватности и идёт вразнос (2019). В общем, с виду 
 молчаливый, тихий, а как напьётся, идёт вразнос – успевай 
 нырнуть под стол (2020).


Так в чем же дело?

Слово разнос существует: Утром комендант схватился за голову и устроил полный разнос дежурившей ночью вахтёрше...
Управление В.п.
Пойти куда, во что (В.п.) —  в лес, в школу. Я бы в летчики пошел... Но ведь нельзя пойти в разнос. Обычное противопоставление существительного и наречия:  надеяться на удачу — идти  наудачу.
Но это же метафорическое сочетание, как бы режим саморазрушения личности или техники. Его можно считать устойчивым сочетанием. Может быть, и считали так раньше, но не сейчас.
Слово вписывается в систему русской орфографии и должно писаться слитно.
Как правильно
 РАЗНОС, -а; м. 1. к Разнести - разносить (1-2, 6, 8-9 зн.). 
 Дневной, вечерний р. почты. 2. Разг. Строгое внушение, 
 выговор, резкая критика. Получать разносы от начальства. 
 Устроить р. кому-л. (сильно отругать). 3. Спец. 
 Неконтролируемое превышение числа оборотов, ведущее к 
 разрушению устройства. Мотор пошёл в р. 

 РАЗНЕСТИ, св. кого-что. 9. Разг. Разругать, разбранить. Вы, 
 конечно, разнесёте меня? Критика разнесла статью в пух и 
 прах. 

Примечание. Мотор пошёл в р.   Дизель работал в. Любопытно!

вразнос - все словари на Грамоте.ру.


К сожалению, ответа не дали вы. Например, Англо-русский универсальный словарь данное сочетание предлагает писать раздельно.

Я больше не стану беспокоить Вас своими ответами, извините.
